# Static template member array sizeof used in method

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, initialization

I have a template class with a static member array, and a method, which needs the size of the array.

```
template <int i>
struct Foo {
    static int data[];
    static int size() {
        return sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
    }
};
```

I want to initialize the array differently for each template specialization.

```
template <>
int Foo<0>::data[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
```

It's working as long as I use this only in one cpp file. But how to use it in multiple files?

If I put the initialization to the header, linking will fail because:

```
multiple definition of `Foo<0>::data'
```

If I put it into one of the cpp files, the others wont compile because:

```
invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘int []’
```

I'm interested in a solution which not changes the array to std::vector.

Comment: Why don't you just define `size()` in the same translation unit as `data`?

Comment: I will have several specializations in different files, but I would not put definitions of size into each one of them.

Comment: Perhaps a general one in the header and specializations in the implementation files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try enclosing it in an unnamed namespace, this will provide an internal linkage and get around the multiple definition of `Foo<0>::data'

```
namespace{
template <int i>
struct Foo {
    static int data[];
    static int size() {
        return sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Why did this answer got downvoted? It seems to solve the problem. Are there any drawbacks in this case?

Comment: On the other hand, I can imagine that a future maintainer will have no idea, why the unnamed namespace is placed there.

Comment: @simon the drawback is that there are actually several copies of the variable across the program (modifying the values of the array would be a problem). The maintenance issue would deserve a comment in the code. I was also surprised by the down votes.

Comment: I haven't thought of that, the actual code the array will be constant.

Comment: @simon with a const array the unnamed namespace will work. However, make sure that nobody adds a non-const static variable in the future (if there is such a need, the class will have to be split)

Comment: This isn't actually solving the problem. It's just creating multiple copies of the same static arrays for each translation unit instead of properly telling each translation unit that the definitions are provided in exactly one place as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30379156/4612476) explains.

Answer (score 1):

If you leave your struct template definition in a header, you may force template instantiation in a translation unit where you initialize data, and prevent it with extern where used, e.g.:

```
// imp.cc: initialization and instantiation
template <>
int Foo<0>::data[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
template struct Foo<0>;

// main.cc: extern declaration and usage:
template<> extern int Foo<0>::size ();
... Foo<0>::size () ...
```

(I've tested it with a small example and clang.)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

template <int i>
struct Foo {
    static int data[];
    static int size() {
        return sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
    }
};

#endif
```

Foo-0.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_0_H
#define FOO_0_H

#include "Foo.h"

// Provide declarations of the members for 0
template <> int Foo<0>::data[];
template <> int Foo<0>::size();

#endif
```

Foo-0.cpp:

```
#include "Foo-0.h"

// Define the members for 0
template <> int Foo<0>::data[] = {10, 20, 30};
template <> int Foo<0>::size()
{
   return sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Foo-0.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << Foo<0>::data[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << Foo<0>::size() << std::endl;
};
```

Output:

```
10
3
```

Comment: does this solution imply that you need to provide the definition for each instantiation of Foo<i>::size()?

Comment: @ComeRaczy, Only for the ones that you want to specialize. You can have a generic implementation in `Foo.h`.

Comment: If I comment out the definition of Foo<0>::size() in Foo-0.cpp, ld complains about the undefined reference to  Foo<0>::size()

Comment: @ComeRaczy, That makes sense. Since `template <> int Foo<0>::size();` is declareds as an explicit specialization, it must be implemented explicitly.

Comment: @ComeRaczy, it's not possilble to provide an explicit specialization of just `Foo<0>::data` and rely on the generic implementation of `Foo<0>::size()`.